# Download from the tree node within a folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, treenode

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    field1.Text = (string)(Session["rolename"]); //from the page before. eg:IT Folder
    field2.Text = (string)(Session["fullname"]);

    if (Page.IsPostBack == false)
    {

        System.IO.DirectoryInfo RootDir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\\Documents and Settings\\itdept\\Desktop\\Files\\"+ field1.Text);
        TreeNode RootNode = OutputDirectory(RootDir, null);
         MyTree.Nodes.Add(RootNode);
    }
}

protected void click(object sender, EventArgs e) //onselectednodechanged from the treenode in aspx page
{
   string file = ("C:\\Documents and Settings\\itdept\\Desktop\\Files\\" + field1.Text + "\\" + MyTree.SelectedValue);
     Response.Clear();
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + file);
    Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
    Response.WriteFile(file); // here is the problem
    Response.End();

}
```

**i can download files from the IT Folder, but in case there is a folder inside the IT Folder and i want to download something from that folder, i cannot download it.
does anyone have an idea how to make all things inside a folder even in a folder is downloadable?
thank you. :D

Comment: Could you post the code for OutputDirectory ?